# UITableView cell sometimes fails to update image, but displays fine after scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

Just to rule out the obvious, I am updating the UI from the main thread and I've read a bunch of similar questions. Sadly, none of them helped.

In brief: the app tries to get an image for the current cell from its local cache. If it fails, it starts a background thread to download the image and then update the UI from the main thread. This works 90% of the time. When it doesn't, the `imageView` in the cell stays empty. It's interesting that this always happens with the same images.

However, the image gets updated as soon as the cell scrolls out of view and then back into view.

There appear to be no significant differences between the images that show up immediately and those that do not.

I also tried updating the cell with `setNeedsDisplay`, but that doesn't work either. What does work, but messes up my animations in addition to being a bit heavy-handed, is `[tableView reloadData]`.

```
// tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
if(!pic) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // download image, add it to the cache etc.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // check if cell is visible
        if ([[tableView visibleCells] containsObject: theCell]) {
          [[theCell imageView] setImage:pict];
          [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:idxp] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: Any chance `idxp` is not the same as `indexPathForCell:theCell` at the point where `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` is called?

Comment: Nope. They're identical. And `[theCell setNeedsDisplay]` doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup, the problem was on my side.

The exact cause was some pretty weird date comparison code. More precisely, this code was failing to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` with the right indexes because two cells had identical dates, which resulted in one cell getting updated twice, and one cell not getting updated at all. I'm not referring to the code provided in the question.

My advice to anybody else who runs into the same kind of problem is to carefully check the parts of your code that update and create the cells in your table view.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a problem where I was downloading images into a UITableViewCell subclass, but the image was sometimes not scaled properly (or not even rendered) until the cell was scrolled off the screen.

**EDIT: Just re-read the question and saw the original poster had already tried setNeedsDisplay, so this probably won't help in this case. I'll leave this answer for anyone else who stumbles across this though**

Telling the cell's imageView to relayout did the trick:

```
- (void)imageDidDownload:(UIImage *)image // Note: custom delegate callback
{
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [self.imageView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. This is because of that I update the image directly. For instance, `[cell.image setImage:imageName];` But I thought that the correct way is that you need  to have a image array, update the image array. Then call the `reloaddata` function of UITableView.

Answer (score -1):

I've also seen that setImage in an image view won't get updated as expected, the solution that I and others use is to assign the UIImageView itself.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `theCell.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pict];`?

Comment: Assigning to the `ImageView` is not possible because `theCell.imageView` is read-only.